# Generating JAXB classes with custom class names

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a schema which names all its elements and complexTypes in capital letters and so all my class names are also in caps.

Can you let me know how to capture this and name the classes in CamelCase?

Ex: Snippet of XSD :

```
<xs:element name="REGISTRATION_DATE">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
        <xs:attribute name="UNIT" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Currently it is generating as : REGISTRATIONDATE .
But I would like to generate class as : RegistrationDate .

Regards,
Satya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin for XJC to do this - the [CamelCase Always plugin](https://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/camelcase-always/).

Comment: The plugin is not maintained anymore and the link just leads to a 404. Any idea what happened? Is there a new feature that makes it obsolete?